# Facebook Login PHP SDK works locally but not on the server

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect

hi my facebook login works fine on my local server, i make the app live, update 'app domains' on the settings page and also the 'Valid OAuth redirect URIs' on the product settings page, i am still getting the error:

"Graph returned an error:Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."

I have tried multiple varieties of the domain, ive tried adding the /index.php page as well as the standard URL to the redirect URI's and still no luck.

Ive made sure the redirect URI in my code matches the one on facebook.

Im sure its something simple im missing but i cant see it

[index.php **request to API made][3]

[protected_page.php **redirect URI page][4]

Comment: Can you please put the screenshot of facebook app and add your here.?

Comment: Hi Gyandeep ive updated the post with the screenshot image links

Comment: please add privacy page URL and logo for app.. And add your here code also..

Comment: i plan on doing so soon would that affect the functionality? i replaced he links since stack only allows 2 pics till i have 10 reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there are reported different variations of this bug recently: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/518422995172099/

I'm going nuts with this issue since yesterday as well and can't seem to validate these domains at all.

Answer (score 0):

They enabled oAuth whitelisting by default. How to fix: https://wp-native-articles.com/blog/news/how-to-fix-facebook-apps-error-cant-load-url-domain-url-isnt-included-apps-domains/

Comment: this didnt work for me. hopefully facebook will get back to me soon with another response